# What is the reason for InvalidOperationException in Enumerable.Aggregate<TSource>?

Tags: .net, linq

Why only one overload throws this exception?

Little update: I understand that there was a design decision made by framework developers. The question is really why that decision has been made, is there a related design pattern or whatever? Because if I was designing that I'd return default(TSource). What is wrong with such approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one overload that throws the exception takes arguments of type `IEnumerable<TSource>` (`this`) and `Func<TSource, TSource, TSource>`. It starts with the first value and accumulates from there. Without a first value (if `source` is empty), there's no way for the function to know what to return.

The other two overloads accept an argument of type `TAccumulate` to act as the seed. Even if `source` is empty in this case, the function can simply return the seed value.

---

**Update**: You ask why the decision was made *not* to simply use `default(T)` in the case of an empty sequence. The answer doesn't boil down to any specific pattern or known idiom, but rather simply to what is (in my opinion) the sensible choice in terms of API design. The point of `Aggregate` is to make it easy for developers to implement calculations for their own domain-specific problems, *without making assumptions about the semantics of those calculations*.

To use `default(T)` in the case of an empty sequence would be making not one but **two** pretty *big* assumptions:

- that this calculation should produce a meaningful result in the case of an empty sequence; and
- that this result should be `default(T)`

As a trivial counter-example to the *first* assumption, let's say I use `Aggregate` to compute the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) of a sequence of integers. This should give me the value occurring most frequently in the sequence, so a result of zero would simply be false (since the value `0` *never* occurs in an empty sequence).

As a counter-example to the *second*, suppose I take the product of reciprocals of a sequence of positive integers:

```
Aggregate [1, 2, 3, ...] -> 1 * 1/2 * 1/3 * ...
```

In this case the result would actually approach zero as the sequence gets *larger*, so a default value of zero would, again, be completely misleading.

Comment: first overload could just return `default(TSource)`, couldn't it?

Comment: oh, did not notice your update... it definitely makes sence, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The version of `Aggregate<TSource>` you are referring to is `Aggregate<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> enumerable)`.

This particular overload of aggregate is the only one which does not contain a seed (read starting value) for the aggregate operation.  This creates an interesting case when the enumeration contains no elements.  The method could do one of the following

- Throw an exception alerting the user to the issue
- Return `default(TSource)`

The author of the library chose to do the first one.  Why I don't specifically know but likely because it was viewed as an ambiguity and it's best to make ambiguities loud vs. succeed (possible incorrectly) silently

The other two overloads have no issue because they have a seed / initial value which can be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The other two overloads provide an initial, seed, value.  With a seed value, the aggregation has something to return even when the source is empty.

Comment: why they cannot just return detault<TSource>? like in SQL where [select sum(a) from empty_table] returns null if that table is empty.

Comment: @the_joric: Obviously, they *could* have; they made a design decision, and that decision was to throw an exception. As a developer you therefore know to check `if (values.Any())` before calling `values.Aggregate(...)`.

Comment: I agree with Dan Tau that it was a design design, but would also not that callers have the option to use the overload that has a seed value if it's possible the source is empty.

Comment: The problem is `default(T)` will often be null, which could a `NullReferenceException` if the user is expecting there to always be a value (since the overloads that include a seed always have a value).  It would still be different behavior from the other two overloads, in that you still need an extra check (a null check instead of an Any check), but NREs are typically more difficult to track down than exceptions that throw from where the problem is coming from.